# How to animate() simultaneously portions of an image?

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-animate

I want to do a special effect on my header slideshow. I have already done the portion that slides several images by fading the old one into the new one.

My header slideshow images are width=1000px; height=400px;

Between the fading of an image to the next one in the slideshow (about 5 seconds), I want to vary the brightness randomly of the image displayed. However, **I want the brightness to vary randomly in sections of equal size** (width=125px; height=100px).

I thought I could have my active image in z-index: 10; and a totally white background in z-index:9; then varying the opacity of the active img would have done sort of the trick (with the exception that it would only have become clearer and never darker).

But there is no way of doing something like this: $active.animate({opacity: Math.random()*0.7}, {***coords1, coords2, coords3,*** duration: Math.random()*200 , queue: false });

May be the solution is to declare 32 variables (as according to my img sizes it splits in 32 blocks of width=125px; height=100px) each containing a portion of the image and then vary the brightness of each simultaneously... but it seems a bit bold to me and I am unsure how to create these 32 variables yet.

Anyone has a better idea to solve my issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a cheap trick that did the job for me.

Basically I was using a fade-in fade-out kind of slideshow, so what I did is add another similar fade-in fade-out slideshow on top with a higher z-index, but this time I prepared predefined masks with pseudo-random black and white squares.

The masks slideshow I played with a higher frequency than the real slideshow, so that many masks apply to the same image and I varied the opacity from 0 to 0.3, which effectively brighten the image on the white squares and darken the image on the black ones.

It did the trick by giving the impression of randomly changing the opacity of an image in tiles.

I hope this will help if someone is willing to do the same effect.